# apple script update a rule for mail, to sort e.g. newsletter

Tags: applescript, apple-mail

Is it possible to use apple script in mail to sort newsletter by updating a rule when I put a email for training in a specific mail folder?

1. in mail is a folder named "trainNewsletter"
2. in mail / rules is a rule "Newsletter" witch move mails into the folder "Newsletter" with
3. specific from-mail-address
4. if there is a mail in the inbox witch from-mail-address is not in the rule "Newsletter" the mail stays in the inbox
5. I move the mail to the folder "trainNewsletter" an the script add the from-mail-address to the rule
6. next time I get an mail with this from-mail-address it moves direkt to the folder "Newsletter"

Comment: "Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results."  [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if moving the mail to another folder will trigger the rule appended to this folder, but maybe you can trigger this rule manually if needed:

Save this as a new mail rule and connect it to your folder *trainNewsletter*, it should get the email's `sender` and add it as a `from is equal to`-rule condition to your rule *Newsletter*:

```
using terms from application "Mail"
    on perform mail action with messages theMessages for rule theRule
        tell application "Mail"
            repeat with thisMessage in theMessages
                -- getting the sender of the email
                set theSender to sender of thisMessage

                -- setting the sender as a rule condition of rule "Newsletter"
                tell rule "Newsletter"
                    make new rule condition with properties {header:"", expression:theSender, rule type:from header, qualifier:equal to value}
                end tell

            end repeat
        end tell
    end perform mail action with messages
end using terms from
```

Enjoy, Michael / Hamburg